# Gram-Schimidt process(trying to understand the projection operator)

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, inner-products, math-history, gram-schmidt

For Gram-Schmidt process, the projection operator is defined by $proj_u(v)=\frac{<v,u>}{<u,u>}u$. Can someone give me an reference for interpreting this projection operator? What do $<v,u>$ and $<u,u>$ represent geometrically? (Given that I have some basic knowledge of how inner product works). By the way, how do people come up with the Gram-Schmidt formula?

Comment: You can interpret the whole ratio of the two inner products as the cosine of the angle between u and v. Then the picture is clear by drawing a right triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This figure might help clarify some of the details:
[image]

Note that the vector $v-proj_u\left(v\right)$ is orthogonal to $u$ in the figure, which is what you are trying to accomplish using Gram-Schmidt.  This process essentially repeats as you include more vectors.

I hope this helps.