# Why is the error vector $e = b - p$ ( Introduction to Linear Algebra of Gilbert Strang)

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices

I have a question in the projection parts (chapter 4 in his book). I don't really understand why $e=b-p$ (when $e$ is error vector). A line goes through the origin in the direction $a=(a_1,...,a_m)$. So we will project $b$ into that line. Can you guys help me to explain it?

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CS35.png)

Comment: Will it be mare comfortable to write $b=p+e$ and see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction)?

Comment: The discussion and answer here may provide a bit more clarity:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571072/gram-schimidt-processtrying-to-understand-the-projection-operator/3571120#3571120 .  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When we project $\mathbf{b}$ onto the vector $\mathbf{a}$, to say a point $p$ in $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{e}=\mathbf{b}-p$ is a line from the point of projection $p$ to the vector $\mathbf{b}$.

The concept of error comes from the line fitting problem.

Finding the best least squares approximation of a line $L$ passing through 3 given vectors $(\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2}, \mathbf{x_3})$ for instance can be thought of as minimising the square of projection distance of the vectors $(min(|\mathbf{x_1} - p_1|^2 + |\mathbf{x_2}-p_2|^2 + |\mathbf{x_3} - p_3|^2)$, where $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ are the points of projection on the line L for the vectors $(\mathbf{x_1}, \mathbf{x_2}, \mathbf{x_3})$ respectively.